# Writing XSLT transformed XML fragments to a XMLStreamWriter

Tags: java, xslt, namespaces, jaxb, saxon

I've got the following problem:

- Large output file (zip), which contains one xml document ("FeatureCollection")
- Relatively small xml fragments
- Each fragment requires to be written as "featureMember" to the XMLStream after XSLT transformation
- Namespace definitions only on "FeatureCollection" (root) tag.

Now, I got this to work by making use of a separate byte-stream for parsing the fragments. I also wrap the XMLStream to avoid that the XSLT transformer (Saxon) opens / closes a document or closes the stream.

However, I feel that the solution is too complicated. It should be possible to take the JAXB context as source (not having an intermediate byte stream). See code-snippet:

```
        try {
            XMLStreamWriterWrapper writer = getWriter( xmlFile );
            for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : prefixMapper.getNamespaces().entrySet() ) {
                writer.setPrefix( entry.getValue(), entry.getKey() );
            }

            writer.getWrapperWriter().writeStartDocument();
            writer.writeStartElement( GML_URI, "FeatureCollection" );

            for ( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : prefixMapper.getNamespaces().entrySet() ) {
                writer.getWrapperWriter().writeNamespace( entry.getValue(), entry.getKey() );
            }

            while ( dtoIterator.hasNext() ) {
                writer.writeStartElement( GML_URI, "featureMember" );
                D dto = dtoIterator.next();
                hideAttributes( dto );

                J jaxb = transformToJaxb( dto );

                Source untransformed = new JAXBSource( jaxbContext, getRootElement( jaxb ) );
                getTransformer().transform( untransformed, new StAXResult( writer) );
                writer.writeEndElement();
            }

            writer.writeEndElement();
            writer.getWrapperWriter().writeEndDocument();
            writer.getWrapperWriter().flush();
            writer.getWrapperWriter().close();
        }
        catch ( IOException | JAXBException | TransformerException | XMLStreamException e ) {
            LOG.error( e );
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( e );
        }
        
private XMLStreamWriterWrapper getWriter( File xmlFile ) throws XMLStreamException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
    xof.setProperty( XMLOutputFactory.IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES, Boolean.TRUE );

    XMLStreamWriter writer = xof.createXMLStreamWriter( new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( xmlFile ) ) );

    return new XMLStreamWriterWrapper( writer );
}
```

The expected result (from non optimized solution):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?><gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:brocom="http://www.broservices.nl/xsd/brocommon/3.0" xmlns:bro="http://www.pdok.nl/bro">
    <gml:featureMember>
        <bro:Characteristics gml:id="BRO_id_1">
            <brocom:broId>id_1</brocom:broId>
        </bro:Characteristics>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <bro:Characteristics gml:id="BRO_id_2">
            <brocom:broId>id_2</brocom:broId>
        </bro:Characteristics>
    </gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

However the result (from code snippet above) is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?><gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:brocom="http://www.broservices.nl/xsd/brocommon/3.0" xmlns:bro="http://www.pdok.nl/bro">
    <gml:featureMember>
        <bro:Characteristics gml:id="BRO_id_1">
            <broId xmlns="http://www.broservices.nl/xsd/brocommon/3.0">id_1</broId>
        </bro:Characteristics>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <bro:Characteristics gml:id="BRO_id_2">
            <broId xmlns="http://www.broservices.nl/xsd/brocommon/3.0">id_2</broId>
        </bro:Characteristics>
    </gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

Questions:

1. the  XMLStreamWriter seems to ignore the property IS_REPAIRING_NAMESPACES. What is wrong?
2. Can I optimize the Saxon transformer so that it operates on partial xml. Ergo: do I really need to wrap the XMLOutputStream so that the transformer does not write an open/close document or close the stream altogether?
3. Am I defining the namespaces correctly (with setPrefix and writeNameSpace).
4. When using a JAXB marshaller, I can set properties on the marshaller like: JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, JAXB_FRAGMENT. Can I do this is this solution as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you could use a Saxon implementation of XMLStreamWriter in place of the one you are using (`Processor.newSerializer().getXMLStreamWriter()`). It's possible this might give you more control and perhaps solve the namespace issues.

Rather than supplying `new StaxResult(writer)` as the second argument of `transform()`, you could try supplying `new net.sf.saxon.stax.ReceiverToXMLStreamWriter(writer)`, and you could then perhaps subclass `ReceiverToXMLStreamWriter` so that the `startDocument()` and `endDocument()` calls do nothing.

As regards XMLStreamWriter handling of namespaces, I'm afraid the API specification is very obscure. I found it helpful to consult http://veithen.github.io/2009/11/01/understanding-stax.html although it has no official standing. I can't offer any guarantee that the Saxon interpretation is what the authors of the API intended (there's no reference implementation or test suite).

Comment: @Mickael Kay: Thanks for your repsonse. The Saxon implementation of the XMLStreamWriter looks promissing. 
 
 Using the proposed ReceiverToXMLStreamWriter gives a nullpointer: at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.getDestinationReceiver(XsltTransformer.java:631)

Comment: Taking the `Processor.newSerializer().getXMLStreamWriter()` without configuration already fixed the problem. </br> The reference was indeed usefull. I now write `startDocument`, `startElement` and directly after initialize the namespaces with `setPrefix` and `writeNamespace`. The writer seems to recognize these and does not add new namespace definitions anymore on nested elements. </br>Thanks.